# What are the "other shared hardware resources" to release when entering the background?

Tags: ios, uikit

The following article from Apple: [Preparing Your UI to Run in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background) states that we should release *shared system resources* in:

> **Prepare your app to be suspended**
>
> ...
>
> "Make sure your app is not holding **any shared system resources** when it
> transitions to the background. If it continues accessing resources
> like the camera or a shared system database after transitioning to the
> background, **the system terminates your app to free up that resource**.
> If you use a system framework to access a resource, check the
> framework’s documentation for guidelines about what to do."

Can anyone provide a list of resources and system frameworks that we should take into consideration?

Comment: I don't think there is an exhaustive list of such system resources. The best thing you can do is to search your app for things that can be shared with other apps. Hardware such as the camera, microphone etc.

Comment: I found this tonight and I was wondering if this applies to core data at all... any thoughts?